# Backup WhatsApp to PC (with all Media)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, backup, whatsapp-messenger

How do I backup my WhatsApp Chats with all media (text, video, audio, position data etc.) and view them on PC?

The backup purpose is not to restore it later, it is to view the data on my pc, just as if it was on my smartphone.

- Solution tested, which doesn't meet the requirements:

  - Copy WhatsApp folder to PC and use [whatsapp-viewer](https://github.com/andreas-mausch/whatsapp-viewer/releases/)

    - The viewer and its HTML Export files do not contain the voice messages

Answer (score 0):

The chats are saved automatically every day in the *WhatsApp*-Folder on your internal storage, and the pictures and videos are there as well. Just copy the whole folder to your PC. WhatsApp restores these files during the installation if it finds them, so if your smartphone breaks, just copy the folder onto the new one (same location) and install WhatsApp again. It's also possible to make a manual backup from the settings. You just have to copy it to your computer every day ...
You could use a tool like the [WhatsApp Viewer](http://andreas-mausch.de/whatsapp-viewer/) to view the files on your PC. I haven't tested this programm, but it looks ok, and you didn't specify what you mean with "view".

Comment: The viewer and its HTML Export files do not contain the voice messages. The folder, which I copied to my PC does contain them, but I can not know, which voice-message belongs to which chat.

Comment: You could use [WhatsApp Web](https://web.whatsapp.com/). You would still need your smartphone, but you could view the data on your PC. I don't know if this fits your requirements ...

Comment: I found an [article](http://heise.de/-2621494) in an german computer magazine which could help you as well. I haven't read it and it costs 1,49 €, but the first few lines sound well ...

Comment: Yes, the view of WhatsApp Web is nice, but it is not an archive, it uses live-data. It does not use my backup.
So a backup with the view of WhatsApp Web would be nice. Or "offline" WhatsApp Web.

Or I ask you: How do you make sure, to view all your chat logs, when WhatsApp shuts down or you don't want to use it anymore (due to changed TOC for example)

Comment: You could use an emulator (e. g. [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com) or [VirtualBox with Android x86](https://www.howtogeek.com/164570/HOW-TO-INSTALL-ANDROID-IN-VIRTUALBOX/)) and install WhatsApp there. I however can't guarantee that it will work perfectly. I know that this is not a very nice solution ...

Comment: If you don't like this either: I'm out of ideas ;-). You can try yourself to find an suitable Database Viewer, or maybe someone else will reply ... You could try to implement the voice message function for yourself in WhatsApp Viewer, the source code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/andreas-mausch/whatsapp-viewer), or you could ask the author to do it ...

Comment: One more thing: you can download [WhatsApp for PC](https://www.whatsapp.com/download/). I just don't know if this is better than WhatsApp Web ...